# Tensorflow: Train two networks in one network

Tags: tensorflow

I face the following problem in Tensorflow: I constructed a network with the following layer sizes:

```
input_0 = 100
input_1 = 1000
output = 10
```

The entire network looks like:

```
[input_0, 300, 500, input_1, 800, 400, output]
```

Now I feed data to `input_0` and run an optimizing step afterwards. Here I want to use the whole network which is straight forward. But after doing that I also want to be able to feed some data into `input_1` and run an optimizing step which runs backwards but only until the `input_1` layer. Is that even possible? I mean there should be a way to do that.

In short: How to train networks `[input_0,...,output]` and `[input_1,...,output`] independently of each other when they are both part of the same graph?

I tried to implement it in Tensorflow which resulted in many errors. I also tried to split the network into two networks. But than I don't know how to connect them properly.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The optimizers accept a `var_list` parameter which will let you only update some weights.

See the documentation for `GradientDescentOptimizer` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer#minimize).

Comment: That would probably solve the optimizing part. But what about feeding the data in the middle of the graph into `input_1`? How do I do that?

Comment: Make one placeholder for each.